# Unable to locate SimpleAmqpClient library for the C++ project on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I try to use the [SimpleAmqpClient](https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient) library to build my multi-agent environment for simulation. I have installed the library after cloning its sources, making them:

```
make
sudo make install
```

After that, I created the

> main.cpp

file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SimpleAmqpClient/SimpleAmqpClient.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

just to try it out.

Also, I have the following

> CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(SampleProject)
include_directories('/usr/local/include/')

find_package(libSimpleAmqpClient REQUIRED)
include_directories(${libSimpleAmqpClient++_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${libSimpleAmqpClient++_LIBRARIES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(SampleProject ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

So, the question is: how to find and link this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, thanks to @RichardHodges. The solution was to use

`find_library()` instead of `find_package()`.

THe final file is the following:

> CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(SampleProject)
include_directories('/usr/local/include/')

find_library(libSimpleAmqpClient REQUIRED)
include_directories(${libSimpleAmqpClient++_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${libSimpleAmqpClient++_LIBRARIES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(SampleProject ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the line

```
target_link_libraries(SampleProject ${LIBS})
```

after the line

```
add_executable(SampleProject ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

This imbues the target `SampleProject` with properties that tell the generator to generate a linker command which reference the libraries you need.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11185456)

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it. :-)

Comment: @rptwsthi, this didn't help. I guess it is due to the naming of library. How should  I name it so that it could be found?

Comment: you'll need to check the documentation for the cmake script that supports finding `libSimpleAmqpClient` - the name looks wrong to be honest. Are you sure you can use find_package() with this library? Perhaps find_library()?

Comment: @RichardHodges, exactly! You saved my day!